# What PUBLIC access means on tables in Oracle?

Tags: oracle-11g

I recieved a communication from my DBA that they want to revoke PUBLIC access and they shared attached screenshot. What does this mean by PUBLIC access on these tables? And what happen if they "Revoke" the access.

[image]

I don't know the query which result is this. Can anyone help to understand this resultset. I want to understand the impact on my application if they revoke this access.

Comment: A lot of those objects aren't actually tables. Examples such as DBMS_SCHEDULER and UTL_FILE are system packages containing procedures and functions for administering the database. Your DBA is right that PUBLIC should probably not have access to many of these. They should be granted to individual users based on the principle of least privilege.

Answer (score 1):

[Grants and Revokes of Privileges to and from the PUBLIC Role](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authorization.htm#DBSEG99967)

> You can grant and revoke privileges and roles from the role PUBLIC.
>
> Because PUBLIC is accessible to every database user, **all privileges**
>   **and roles granted to PUBLIC are accessible to every database user.** By
>   default, PUBLIC does not have privileges granted to it.
>
> Security administrators and database users should grant a privilege or
>   role to PUBLIC only if every database user requires the privilege or
>   role. This recommendation reinforces the general rule that, at any
>   given time, each database user should have only the privileges
>   required to accomplish the current group tasks successfully.
>
> Revoking a privilege from the PUBLIC role can cause significant
>   cascading effects. If any privilege related to a DML operation is
>   revoked from PUBLIC (for example, SELECT ANY TABLE or UPDATE ON emp),
>   then all procedures in the database, including functions and packages,
>   must be reauthorized before they can be used again. Therefore, be
>   careful when you grant and revoke DML-related privileges to or from
>   PUBLIC.

If you do not use the above packages, it will not have any impact on your application.